# Function to graph and save columns in a dataframe

Tags: r

I am trying to make a function that I give the column name and it will make a graph and save the graph, but not sure the correct syntax. My idea:

```
graph_it <- function (col_name) {
   graph_name <- paste(col_name,'.png', sep='')

ggplot(data = CPI, aes(y = col_name, x = DATE )) + geom_line() + 
theme_bw() +
theme(panel.border = element_blank(),
      panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
      panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
      panel.background = element_blank()) +
ggtitle("YOY") + 
scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)

ggsave(graph_name, width = 5, height = 5)
}
```

y = col_name does not work. How can I pass the column name as a variable in this function?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are passing the column name as string. If you want to use mappings that use strings, use `aes_string()`. For example

```
graph_it <- function (col_name) {
  graph_name <- paste0(col_name, '.png')

  ggplot(data = CPI, aes(x = DATE )) + 
  geom_line(aes_string(y = col_name)) + 
  ggtitle("YOY") 

  ggsave(graph_name, width = 5, height = 5)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main thing you needed to change was to switch `y = col_name` to be `y = CPI[, col_name]`

```
graph_it <- function (col_name) {
  graph_name <- paste(col_name,'.png', sep='')

  ggplot(data = CPI, aes(y = CPI[, col_name], x = DATE )) + geom_line() + 
    theme_bw() +
    theme(panel.border = element_blank(),
          panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
          panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
          panel.background = element_blank()) +
    ggtitle("YOY") + 
    scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)

  ggsave(graph_name, width = 5, height = 5)
}


# Just for testing
CPI <- mtcars
CPI$DATE <- seq(as.Date("2000/1/1"), by = "month", length.out = 32)

graph_it("mpg")
```